# Cannot get HtmlNode with using XPath retrieved from same HtmlNode

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

There is property `XPath` of `HtmlNode`, if I get that and use it to get single node from root `HtmlNode` it gives me exception `Expression must evaluate to a node-set.'`

So here what I am doing:

```
HtmlNode someNode=getNode(rootNode);
HtmlNode foundNode=rootNode.SelectSingleNode(someNode.XPath);
```

Structure does not change during calls. Any clue why it is not working ? I get `XPath` like this: `/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/#text[1]`

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code - especially the method getNode(); and preferably also the url to the the site you try to scrape.

Comment: I don't think that they matter. I mean, my question is, why i cannot use `XPath` of property to get it from parent of it. But if it can help. this is the [link](https://acerrecertified.com/acer-34-widescreen-lcd-monitor-display-uw-qhd-3440-x-1440-4-ms-ips-x34-bmiphz-scratch-dent). I just get the node which contains some text, that is all.

Comment: and I look for text "out of stock", As I said I can give another example, where I cannot use this `XPath` from actual node, to get it from root node.

Answer (score 1):

I think it mattered. Because first of your xpath is a mess and hard to maintain if they just change one small thing on their site. Any way below is the correct way of doing what you're trying to do.

```
HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/text()[1]");

 Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
```

Easier way to get it is like this.

```
HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='alert alert-error'][string-length(normalize-space(text()))>0]");
```

Here we select the div-tag with a class attribute that equals 'alert alert-error'. But we only want it if it has a length that is greater than 0.

Comment: the thing is it is returned by property, so i thought it can be used to send to `SelectSingleNode()`. So thing is to remove `#` and add `()` to end ?

Comment: And why I didn't want to give example link, I want implement common solution, that searches for text, finds node, gets `XPath` of that node, and uses it for sniffing. So that is why I cannot hardcode it.

Comment: It seems that only last part have some problem, it is not what I want, i can just remove exact node's name from it, in my case it is `#text` and check parent  `div` element.

Comment: You have to be specific about what you want.
First you say that you want to implement a common solution - but your xpath gives no indication of such. Both your code and comments are cryptic. I've already told you why your xpath doesn't work - It's now up to you to apply the fix.

Comment: you know what the expression "like this" means? i have not mentioned that given XPath is exact case, and will be same. Above XPath is property value which I get from HtmlNode.XPath, if you don't have clue about how internally this works, then please don't answer. Let me explain this "common solution" to you again. I have a link and some text. I want to find XPath to node where this text occurs, and get it by that XPath. And above XPath, just example case

Answer (score 0):

Without providing us with some code it's very difficult for us to figure out what the problem is.

If you just want to find a specific string, I would suggest you to use [xpath functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions), like this:

```
"//*[contains(text(), 'string you are looking for')]"
```

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack` has `HtmlNode` type, which has `XPath` property. And there is `SelectSingleNode` function that requires `XPath` string. When I take `XPath` of `HtmlNode` (from `HtmlDocument`, lets say root), and send it to function (`root.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode()`), I assume I will get same `HtmlNode`, but it gives exception. I don't know any other way to explain this question, but anyways I solved problem by removing last child's name from `XPath`